# Inverting an Order-Preserving Minimal Perfect Hash Function in Better than O(K*lg N) Running Time

Tags: algorithm, performance, combinations

I am trying to find a more efficient solution to a combinatorics problem than the solution I have already found.

Suppose I have a set of **N** objects (indexed **0..N-1**) and wish to consider each subset of size **K** (**0<=K<=N**). There are **S=C(N,K)** (i.e., "N choose K") such subsets. I wish to map (or "encode") each such subset to a unique integer in the range **0..S-1**.

Using **N=7** (i.e., indexes are **0..6**) and **K=4** (**S=35**) as an example, the following mapping is the goal:
**0 1 2 3 --> 0

0 1 2 4 --> 1

...

2 4 5 6 --> 33

3 4 5 6 --> 34**

**N** and **K** were chosen small for the purposes of illustration. However, in my actual application, **C(N,K)** is far too large to obtain these mappings from a lookup table. They must be computed on-the-fly.

In the code that follows, `combinations_table` is a pre-computed two-dimensional array for fast lookup of **C(N,K)** values.

All code given is compliant with the **C++14** standard.

If the objects in a subset are ordered by increasing order of their indexes, the following code will compute that subset's encoding:

```
template<typename T, typename T::value_type N1, typename T::value_type K1>
typename T::value_type combination_encoder_t<T, N1, K1>::encode(const T &indexes)
{
   auto offset{combinations_table[N1][K1] - combinations_table[N1 - indexes[0]][K1]};

   for (typename T::value_type index{1}; index < K1; ++index)
   {
      auto offset_due_to_current_index{
           combinations_table[N1 - (indexes[index-1] + 1)][K1 - index] -
           combinations_table[N1 - indexes[index]][K1 - index]
                                      };

      offset += offset_due_to_current_index;
   }

   return offset;
}
```

Here, template parameter **T** will be either a `std::array<>` or `std::vector<>` holding a collection of indexes we wish to find the encoding for.

This is essentially an "order-preserving minimal perfect hash function", as can be read about here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function

In my application, the objects in a subset are already naturally ordered at the time of encoding, so I do not incur the added running time of a sort operation. Therefore, my total running time for encoding is that of the algorithm presented above, which has **O(K)** running time (i.e., linear in **K** and not dependent on **N**).

The code above works fine. The interesting part is trying to invert this function (i.e., to "decode" an encoded value back into the object indexes that produced it).

For decoding, I could not come up with a solution with linear running time.

Instead of direct calculation of the indexes that correspond to an encoded value (which would be **O(K)**), I ended up implementing a binary search of the index space to find them. This results in a running time that is (no worse than, but which we'll call) **O(K*lg N)**. The code to do this is as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename T::value_type N1, typename T::value_type K1>
void combination_encoder_t<T, N1, K1>::decode(const typename T::value_type encoded_value, T &indexes)
{
   typename T::value_type offset{0};
   typename T::value_type previous_index_selection{0};

   for (typename T::value_type index{0}; index < K1; ++index)
   {
      auto lowest_possible{index > 0 ? previous_index_selection + 1 : 0};
      auto highest_possible{N1 - K1 + index};

      // Find the *highest* ith index value whose offset increase gives a
      // total offset less than or equal to the value we're decoding.
      while (true)
      {
         auto candidate{(highest_possible + lowest_possible) / 2};

         auto offset_increase_due_to_candidate{
                   index > 0 ?
                      combinations_table[N1 - (indexes[index-1] + 1)][K1 - index] -
                      combinations_table[N1 - candidate][K1 - index]
                             :
                      combinations_table[N1][K1] -
                      combinations_table[N1 - candidate][K1]
                                              };

         if ((offset + offset_increase_due_to_candidate) > encoded_value)
         {
            // candidate is *not* the solution
            highest_possible = candidate - 1;
            continue;
         }

         // candidate *could* be the solution. Check if it is by checking if candidate + 1
         // could be the solution. That would rule out candidate being the solution.
         auto next_candidate{candidate + 1};

         auto offset_increase_due_to_next_candidate{
                   index > 0 ?
                      combinations_table[N1 - (indexes[index-1] + 1)][K1 - index] -
                      combinations_table[N1 - next_candidate][K1 - index]
                             :
                      combinations_table[N1][K1] -
                      combinations_table[N1 - next_candidate][K1]
                                                   };

         if ((offset + offset_increase_due_to_next_candidate) <= encoded_value)
         {
            // candidate is *not* the solution
            lowest_possible = next_candidate;
            continue;
         }

         // candidate *is* the solution
         offset += offset_increase_due_to_candidate;
         indexes[index] = candidate;
         previous_index_selection = candidate;
         break;
      }
   }
}
```

Can this be improved on? I'm looking for two categories of improvements:

1. Algorithmic improvements that yield better than the **O(K*lg N)**
   running time of the code given; ideally, direct calculation would be possible, giving the same **O(K)** running time the encoding process has
2. Code improvements that execute the
   given algorithm faster (i.e., that lower any constant factor hidden
   within the **O(K*lg N)** running time)

Comment: I don't understand, how did you get `O(log N)` running time? Your outer loop is `O(K)`, so it should be at least O( K * ? ) or O( K + ? ). Do you have a proof that both loops produce O(log(N)) running time? I have a suspicion that it's actually something like O(K + N) and that it's impossible to do better. It's certainly not  O(log(N)), as you are filling the result, which is O(K).

Comment: You might want to post this under computer science, math or math in the stackexchange sites

Comment: Aivean, you are correct regarding the O(lg N) running time. I have made corrections to my statements regarding running time, and I have attempted to make other clarifications as well.

Comment: This question is being discussed on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412875/what-makes-a-good-performance-question-on-so)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Take a look at the [recursive formula for combinations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Recursive_formula):

[image: recursive formula for combinations]

---

Suppose you have a combination space `C(n,k)`. You can divide that space into two subspaces:

- `C(n-1,k-1)` all combinations, where the first element of the original set (of length `n`) is present
- `C(n-1, k)` where first element is not preset

If you have an index X that corresponds to a combination from `C(n,k)`, you can identify whether the first element of your original set belongs to the subset (which corresponds to `X`), if you check whether `X` belongs to either subspace:

- `X < C(n-1, k-1)` :  belongs
- `X >= C(n-1, k-1)`: doesn't belong

Then you can recursively apply the same approach for `C(n-1, ...)` and so on, until you've found the answer for all `n` elements of the original set.

---

Python code to illustrate this approach:

```py
import itertools, math

n=7
k=4
stuff = list(range(n))

# function that maps x into the corresponding combination
def rec(x, n, k, index):
  if n==0 and k == 0:
    return index

  # C(n,k) = C(n-1,k-1) + C(n-1, k)
  # C(n,0) = C(n,n) = 1
  c = math.comb(n-1, k-1) if k > 0 else 0
  if x < c:
    index.add(stuff[len(stuff)-n])
    return rec(x, n-1, k-1, index)
  else:
    return rec(x - c, n-1, k, index)

# Test:
for i,eta in enumerate(itertools.combinations(stuff, k)):
  comb = rec(i, n, k, set())
  print(f'{i} {eta} {comb}')
```

Produced output:

```
0 (0, 1, 2, 3) {0, 1, 2, 3}
1 (0, 1, 2, 4) {0, 1, 2, 4}
2 (0, 1, 2, 5) {0, 1, 2, 5}
3 (0, 1, 2, 6) {0, 1, 2, 6}
4 (0, 1, 3, 4) {0, 1, 3, 4}
5 (0, 1, 3, 5) {0, 1, 3, 5}
...
33 (2, 4, 5, 6) {2, 4, 5, 6}
34 (3, 4, 5, 6) {3, 4, 5, 6}
```

---

This approach is `O(n)` (while your approach seems to be `O( k * log(n) )` (?) ), and it should have fairly small constant if rewritten iteratively. I'm not sure if it will yield an improvement (needs to be tested).

I also wonder how large your typical `k` and `n` values are? I assume they should be small enough so that C(n,k) still fits into 64bits?

Of course, you can use precomputed tables instead of `math.comb`, replace recursion with iteration (it's tail recursion, so you don't need stack), and use array instead of the set for the result.

Comment: Aivean, most of the cases I care about have C(N,K) that fits in 64 bits, but some don't! So, I wish I had 128-bit integers, but I don't, so I'll be ignoring those cases for now.

Comment: Aivean, you are correct that my approach has O(K*lg N) time, and I have updated my post to correct my statements. Thank you!

Comment: @Dave, have you considered my proposed approach? While it's O(n) (technically, O(n+k)), it's simpler and could be faster in practice, if rewritten carefully. Unfortunately I don't have time to benchmark both solutions against each other.

Comment: Aivean, sorry, was getting late last night. Oh yes, I've definitely considered your solution! I just had to think it through, and I also had to install Python 3.8 to run it. I'll be implementing it in C++ and will see if it runs faster in practice.

I have a feeling that my (revised) stated goal of "direct calculation" of the decoded indexes (what I initially called a "closed-form solution") is not possible and that some sort of search is unavoidable. I may therefore follow the suggestion made by @tarik of posting this in the math forum. Excellent work, thank you!

Comment: Aivean, sorry, I didn't fully answer your question about N and K. Was getting late! In my application, N is fixed at 52. 5<=K<=52. You may notice that no K will yield a C(52,K) that won't fit in 64 bits. The reason I said 64 bits won't address all my cases is that in my application, there's another embedded factor of C(K,5) that comes into play. The worst case is C(52,28)*C(28,5)=41,905,116,034,114,788,000. This requires 66 bits. But that doesn't affect the general-purpose solution I was seeking, so I did not mention it in my post.

Comment: @Dave, thank you for the clarifications. I'm sorry if my comment pressed you to reply ASAP, that was not my intention. Please let me know, if or when you find a better solution or have any other relevant updates regarding this problem.

Comment: Aivean, no prob at all and... You'll be happy to know your algorithm performed *extremely* well in practice, even better than the encoding. What took 4.6 seconds with my algorithm takes 0.02 seconds with yours (N=52, K=7)! Also, for comparison, encoding takes 0.6 seconds. Very appreciative of you freely giving your time to understand the problem, prompt me to work through errors I had made, devise a solution, and present that solution in a very cogent manner!

Comment: @Dave, thank you for letting me know. I'm indeed happy to hear that. However, I can't help but think that decoding taking less than encoding is suspicious. Are you sure that it's working as intended? I'd appreciate it if you added the code that you've benchmarked to the question.

Comment: Aivean, before benchmarking for speed, I had added code to print out the encoded values and their corresponding combinations to a file. All of the encoded values were present and looked to be correct. In addition, I have added my C++ implementation of your algorithm to the original question.

Comment: @Dave, thank you. I just have thought of another improvement. If you replace `while(true)` with `while(k != 0)`, you'll will have early exit (when index is already filled) and you can eliminate `break` and `k > 0` check down the line entirely.

Comment: @Dave, [Something like this](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/073136bbfd7a17c5f24da955bb6bb664) (I haven't tested it).

Comment: Aivean, I tested, your improvements work!

Comment: Sets are unordered, better use lists. For example for [n=9, k=3](https://tio.run/##ZVFNa8MwDL37VzzoYTZLS0ovW1l22V/YbeyQJUprksrBVqBj7Ld3ctOWwi62Pp6kp6fxW/aBN09jPJ38YQxR4IWihDCkAoda9sZw9Wz6amOSTF2HCoNPYmPNO7LsnDELdBM34gND9rVo1ZhwhGcJGiA0IUZKY@DW8069w5fnOsNNSx0iNfZYgAv0hda0dHRbA/gOXFUlam7Ro6pQ5igULlPkGWg0ssCb5aJ3ykuN5brol2uHx4uD3t0w5QVTcDbWGm/0zyuuMqcLPlfr7B6vKEFDIpQzmyNe0MwczsNXddvasyQfA/FsuSV/unua1@Uura8LKiS33v6DYonmCr@BVeB3SrI1XYjwBUmtGRBPB4q1kL0dbHWnbZoZZQXOeuaUrpun@KvaicS6TGaMeizbPfz4X/xof30zXj@ZxoFsdlw@Qs49uNPpDw) you produce combinations like `{0, 8, 2}`.

Comment: [more_itertools.nth_combination](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.nth_combination) btw appears to use the same algorithm, just iteratively (see the "source" link there).

Comment: @KellyBundy, yep, you are correct, the only difference is they are using [multiplicative formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Multiplicative_formula) for `C` instead of pre-computed tables, quite clever.

Comment: @Aivean Yeah, quite clever. I've used that formula myself before, but only in the first way they're using it, i.e., computing some nCk from scratch. I don't think I've used it like they do later for moving to a "neighbor". I guess this might even be faster than using a table.

Comment: @KellyBundy *"I guess this might even be faster than using a table."* — I'd say it depends on the memory pressure. If tables are in L1 cache, they probably would be faster, especially  since you don't need to calculate initial `C`. But that's just my educated guess, only benchmarks can give the real answer.

Comment: Yeah, for the initial `C` value I do suspect a table would be faster. I meant the later adjustment with just two or three operations. But yes, only benchmarks could perhaps really tell (and I'm not used enough to C++ to do that properly).

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, I'd like to add a C++ implementation of the algorithmic improvement given by @aivean (which proved to be very effective) for decoding an encoded value back into the indexes that produced it.

As in the original post, `combinations_table` is a pre-computed two-dimensional array for fast lookup of **C(N,K)** values.

```
template<typename T, typename T::value_type N1, typename T::value_type K1>
void combination_encoder_t<T, N1, K1>::decode(const typename T::value_type encoded_value, T &indexes)
{
   auto n{N1};
   auto k{K1};
   auto x(encoded_value);
   T1 index{0};

   while (k != 0)
   {
      auto c{combinations_table[n-1][k-1]};

      if (x < c)
      {
         indexes[index++] = N1 - n;
         --k;
      }
      else
         x -= c;

      --n;
   }
}
```